# Timber\ImageHelper cropping not working on specific server

Tags: timber

Images are not being cropped by Timber when I deploy my site to production. It does work in my development environment. I'm using the following code:

```
<img src="{{ Image(fields.image).src|resize(1160, 540, 'center') }}"
  sizes="80vw"
  srcset="
    {{ Image(fields.image).src|resize(2320, 1080, 'center') }} 2320w,
    {{ Image(fields.image).src|resize(1940, 810, 'center') }} 1940w,
    {{ Image(fields.image).src|resize(1160, 540, 'center') }} 1160w,
    {{ Image(fields.image).src|resize(870, 405, 'center') }} 870w,
    {{ Image(fields.image).src|resize(580, 270, 'center') }} 580w"
 alt="{{ fields.image.alt }}" />
```

The image is filled with original images and not the cropped versions. You can see a live example here: https://skuario.com/landingpage/

I feel like this is related to the server environment, so I was wondering if there are any server requirements for Timber\ImageHelper to work.

PHP info here: https://skuario.com/phpinfo.php

Answer (score 0):

The PHP build installed on the server must not have image manipulation extensions. You sould install php72-php-gd or the one ;atching your PHP version and the images will be generated.

Comment: Thanks for your response. We decided to use an alternative way to crop and resize the images.